# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen log/production.log (heroku deploy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy a non-master branch to heroku with command:

```
git push heroku staging:master
```

but the following error happens. With master branch, everything works fine.

```
  Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/log/production.log
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environments/production.rb:85:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environments/production.rb:85:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/log/production.log
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environments/production.rb:85:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environments/production.rb:85:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_82c61778093d5c199dedf47797381313/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

production.rb line 85:

`config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log",Rails.env + ".log"), 5, 100*1024*1024)`

[complete output](https://gist.github.com/edipofederle/9a7fa4249a4373623a1142f0f5d2603f)

[production.rb file](https://gist.github.com/edipofederle/d3734a5752a4d8ac09c3ce1fb471f0ae)

**UPDATE:**

Well, the problem is with the line 85, but I don't know why

someone has some suggestions about it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you should be posting all your deployment log and not just the error from it. It fails on `config/environments/production.rb:85`, but who knows what is there. So, you should post that file too.

Comment: sorry for that. @gen I updated the question with more informations

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the `log` directory has been removed from your git repository. Perhaps on your new branch you have `git rm`'d all its contents? Git will automatically remove any directories that don't have any files, so normally people use a `.keep` or `.gitkeep` file to keep things like `log` from going away completely.

Also you should make sure your `.gitignore` is not this:

```
/log
```

but this:

```
/log/*.log
```